# 2D room with electron-point-charges (stability)

Tags: electrostatics, charge, simulations, computational-physics, stability

Is there a fast way to find out stable #"point charges" & constellation for this kind of Simulation. The 2D repeating itselve in each direction till infinity, so i've a kind of symetrie here.

[image: 2D Supersymetric Charges]

Red is X-Value of the norm(F-Vector)
Green is Y-Value of the norm(F-Vector)

(Added Damping already but still get no stable constellations)
GitRep: [CodeRepository](https://github.com/schwenk/EndlessTilesAkaSupersymetricFields)

2Charges with potential lines:

[image: 2Charges with potential lines]

Comment: It might be useful to provide a bit more information about what "this kind of simulation" actually is, perhaps also define "constillation" as I'm unfamiliar with that word (though I'm familiar with a *constellation*, but that's not what you mean).

Comment: Stability in what sense? Opposite free charges will merge, and same sign free charges disperse.

Comment: Yes but if I've just one charge it doesn*t disperse itself. But if I've more of them I get movement where I didn't add a initial velocity.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: yes, but i didn't knew that it exist.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the final problem was a bug in the code which calculate the forces.
[Repository -> glan.cpp -> line160 <](https://github.com/schwenk/EndlessTilesAkaSupersymetricFields/commit/762c92abcf9ee07b3a2304133657490a1ba0c933) 
I added the Vectors of the Distances between the points not their force-vectors.

Here are some results:

2Charges:
[image: 2Charges]

3Charges:
[image: 3Charges]

9Charges:
[image: 9Charges]

16Charges:
[image: 16Charges]

All charges have equal electrical charge .

Comment: what exactly are we looking at?  What do the colors represent?

Comment: it looks like you still might have a bug?  The charge separation doesn't look isotropic on the '3Charges' plot.